# Rails 4 Heroku Mysql to Postgres Dump Pending Migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I've converted my `mysql db to postgres`.

I'm used the following to import it to the db:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore database 'http://app.com' --app
```

This creates all the tables and imports the data.

The problem I have is with the following:

```
heroku run rake db:seed --app
```

Then I get a list of pending migrations.

Is there a way to ignore these, reset it, or am I doing this all wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure of an official way but you can always delete migrations if they no longer apply or you could populate `schema_migrations` manually or include the `schema_migrations` table in your data transfer.

Comment: I added the versions manually and it worked out fine. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept those answers, that might be better for people with similar questions.